# Write Build Output from Docker Container to Host

Tags: docker, vue.js, containers, volume

I have a simple dockerfile like this

```
# develop stage
FROM node:alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN npm run build
```

and I am pretty sure in the container there's /app/dist as the built artifact after docker run finishes, and I would like to export it from the container to the outside host system by using a volume like this:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/artifacts:/app/dist test-vue
```

but nothing writes to the artifacts directory that I created. Any thoughts?

Comment: You might want to add `WORKDIR /app` to your build stage too

Answer (score 2):

Using `-v $(pwd)/artifacts:/app/dist` will replace the content of the container by the host's content.

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount.

If you want to export you need to copy the files into a volume after the container started. There are some samples for back/restore volume [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

```
docker exec <container> cp <src> <dst>
```